# Show if a product of coprime numbers is a perfect square, so are the numbers - without FTA

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove: $$\text{If }\gcd(a,b)=1\text{ and }ab=n^2,\text{ then }a,b\text{ are also perfect squares.}$$  Assume everyone is a positive integer, etc.  Unless I'm deluding myself, this is pretty easy to show using unique prime factorization.

But I want to do it without using primes or the (usual statement of the) FTA.  That is, using *coprime* is fine, using the so-called Bezout identity (XGCD algorithm), etc. is fine.  Is this even possible without essentially defining at least irreducibles, if not primes and prime factorization, along the way?

(See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53651/logical-equivalences-for-fta) for a more vague question I asked a while ago on this.)

Comment: See my [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/284651/23500) which uses only properties of gcds. Note the in $\Bbb Z$ (or any domain where nonzero nonunits factor into irreducibles), the existence of gcds is equivalent to uniqueness of factorization into irreducibles, since it easily implies that irreducibles are prime.

Comment: A very related question: Let $R$ be a Bezout domain. If $a,b$ are coprime and $ab$ is a square, does it follow that $a,b$ are squares ?

Comment: @Amr Yes, Bezout domains are gcd domains, so the above-linked proof works.

Comment: @MathGems Yes I know. I was just telling the OP that this may be a better way to ask the question

Comment: @MathGems - nice, yes you are right about this.  Maybe I should just be asking about Bezout domains instead - haven't thought about the tower of domains in years, thanks.  I up-voted MathGems' earlier answer, best I could do here.

Comment: So ... do you think that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286099/prove-that-if-perfect-squares-divide-each-other-then-so-do-the-originals-with admits a Bezout/gcd domain solution?

Comment: @MathGems - if you post your answer here I'll accept, otherwise maybe I should just close the question?

Comment: @MathGems " if you post your answer here I'll" vote up...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) and [this meta answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments/1149#1149), I will post @MathGems answer here as community wiki just so it's easier to find.  (If they return they can post and I'll delete this.)[Directly quoted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284636/if-a-and-b-are-relatively-prime-and-ab-is-a-square-then-a-and-b-are-squares/284651#284651):

---

Alternatively, and more generally, one can use gcds to *explicitly* show $\rm\:a,b\:$ are squares. Writing $\,\rm(m,n,\ldots)\:$ for $\rm\: gcd(m,n,\ldots)$ we have:

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ \color{#C00}{c^2 = ab}\, \Rightarrow\ a = (a,c)^2,\ b = (b,c)^2\: $ if $\rm\ \color{#0A0}{(a,b,c)} = 1\ $ and $\rm\:a,b,c\in \mathbb N$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ \ \ (a,c)^2 =\: (a^2,\color{#C00}{c^2},ac)\: =\: (a^2,\color{#C00}{ab},ac)\: =\: a\,\color{#0A0}{(a,b,c)} = a.\: $ Similarly $\rm \,(b,c)^2 = b.\ \ $ **QED**

Yours is the special case $\rm\:(a,b) = 1\ (\Rightarrow\ (a,b,c) = 1)$. The above proof uses only universal gcd laws (associative, commutative, distributive), so it generalizes to any gcd domain/monoid (where, generally, prime factorizations need not exist, hence the above proof is more general).

Comment: It is clear that if $x$ divides $a$ and $c$ then $x^2$ divides each of $a^2,c^2, ac$. So $(a,c)^2\leq (a^2,c^2,ac).$ But how do you show the reverse inequality? And how do you show the second inequality in the proof?

Comment: I think this is general property of gcd "arithmetic" (an exercise in some texts?); recall that I'm just copying another answer here for reference.